# Wrong data moving from TListbox to TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am working on Delphi 7. I have one TListBox and one TStringGrid with two columns (with no fixed row or column). I have data in the TListBox as follows:

Available Elements - a123 (a123)
Available Elements - a1234 (a1234)
Available Elements - a12345 (a12345)

And the TStringGrid is having following data as follows:

Column1    Column2

a1         Available Elements - a1
a2         Available Elements - a12

If I select the first item in the TListbox i.e. a123 and execute following button click event procedure, then the last item data ie a12345 is getting moved into the grid.

Could anybody put the focus on what I am doing wrong in the following code. Following code moves the seleted item in the TListbox to TStringgird's two columns:

```
procedure TForm1.btnMoveLeftClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sString : String;
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
      {-- Is this status selected? --}
      if ListBox1.Selected[i] then
      begin
        sString := Trim(ListBox1.Items[i]);

        {-- Delete selected status. --}
          ListBox1.Items.Delete (i);

        if ((grdVFormDetails.RowCount >= 1) And (Trim(grdVFormDetails.Cells[0, 0]) <> EmptyStr)) then
          grdVFormDetails.RowCount := grdVFormDetails.RowCount+1;

        grdVFormDetails.Cols[1].Add(Copy(sString, 1, Pos('(', sString) - 1));

        sString := Copy(sString, Pos('(', sString) + 1, Length(sString));
        sString := Copy(sString, Pos('(', sString) + 1, Length(sString) - 1);

        grdVFormDetails.Cols[0].Add(sString);


        break;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is the listbox defined as multi-select?

Comment: No, the listbox is not defined as multi-select.

Comment: Why are you using a for loop at all if you are breaking on the delete?  You could simply use `ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex]` if mutli-select is off. What else are you doing in that loop that you are not showing?

Comment: Yes, I have done the changes as Jachguate suggested, then also same issue is happening.

Comment: Wait, this makes no sense to me: *If I select the first item in the TListbox i.e. a123 and execute following button click event procedure, then the last item data ie a12345 is getting moved into the grid.*, and if you select the second item in the list box, the second item from the end will be moved ? How will work moving from the grid to list box ?

Comment: For that reason I was asking how could I attach my source code, so everyone could download and test it. I have already given the entire source code, but GUI is missing. If possible tell me how to upload my source code of the sample project.

Comment: Okay I have added the GUI details and source code also in my question,please refer it. Now try to add the data into the grid by adding any value (with alpha numeric also) into the edit box which is kept on top of grid and list box, then press on "Go" button, this will add the data into the grid. Add total five items in the grid. Then move the record no. 3 from grid into list box using ">" button, then move 4th and 5th records in the grid one by one. Now the list box would be having 3 items.

Comment: Now select the first item in the list box, then if you put the break point in "<" button's click event and then press "<" button. Then execute the code line by line, you would see the right data is getting added into the grid, and now press "F9" key. Here you would see the last item in the list box is moved into the grid and the same is exist in the list box also. But item no.1 would not be there in the list box. But if you see the two edit boxes kept down side of the grid, those edit boxes are having correct values. This means there is no error in the code. I feel issue is with TStringGrid.

Comment: There are few things to improve. Why not to have two variables, something like `ItemID`, which will hold the value from inside the parentheses and `ItemText` which will hold the rest of the input string. Then you can simply use `Cells[]` to assign the value. Also that input string parsing you should do from the end to the beginning, what if there will be a string like `Text (comment) - (a12345)`. If you'll parse it your current way, you'll extract `comment` instead of `a12345`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you want to parse the input string like this:

```
'Some text (comment) etc. (12345)'
```

into a part with a trimmed string from the beginning to the first opening parenthesis (first from the end) of the input string to get a value like this:

```
'Some text (comment) etc.'
```

and the string from inside the last parentheses of the input string:

```
'12345'
```

If so, you can use the code that follows. Note that is expected to have list box items terminated by closing parentheses. You may check the [`commented version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13846963/2) of this code or download a [`sample project`](http://projects-stackoverflow-tlama.googlecode.com/files/13833739.ZIP) if you want.

Here is the part, which *moves* the focused item from the list box to the string grid:

```
procedure TForm1.MoveLeftButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
  ItemID: string;
  ItemText: string;
begin
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex = -1 then
    Exit;

  S := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
  for I := Length(S) - 1 downto 1 do
  begin
    if S[I] = '(' then
    begin
      ItemID := Trim(Copy(S, I + 1, Length(S) - I - 1));
      ItemText := Trim(Copy(S, 1, I - 1));
      with StringGrid1 do
      begin
        if (Cells[0, RowCount - 1] <> '') and
          (Cells[1, RowCount - 1] <> '')
        then
          RowCount := RowCount + 1;
        Cells[0, RowCount - 1] := ItemID;
        Cells[1, RowCount - 1] := ItemText;
      end;
      ListBox1.Items.Delete(ListBox1.ItemIndex);
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And here is the part which *moves* the selected row from the string grid to the list box:

```
procedure TForm1.MoveRightButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  RowIndex: Integer;
begin
  RowIndex := StringGrid1.Selection.Top;
  if (StringGrid1.Cells[0, RowIndex] <> '') and
    (StringGrid1.Cells[1, RowIndex] <> '') then
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(
      Trim(StringGrid1.Cells[1, RowIndex]) + ' (' +
      Trim(StringGrid1.Cells[0, RowIndex]) + ')'
    );
    for I := RowIndex to StringGrid1.RowCount - 2 do
      StringGrid1.Rows[I].Assign(StringGrid1.Rows[I + 1]);
    if StringGrid1.RowCount > 1 then
      StringGrid1.RowCount := StringGrid1.RowCount - 1
    else
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[0, 0] := '';
      StringGrid1.Cells[1, 0] := '';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: A Huge Thank you TLama and everybody. I really appreciate your great help specially TLama and Jachguate. With this I would like to thank you every one in the same manner. Jachguate, sorry I included my entire code very late, I thought there would be a problem in my event procedure code, so I just wanted to put focus on that to avoid unnecessary area, but as the discussion went on, I found the importance of including the entire source code. @TLama, I found your code is just rocking :) , but could you please tell me what is the issue in my code which moves the item from ListBox to the Grid ?

Comment: You're welcome! About the question of an issue in your code from your last comment, is it still actual ?

Answer (score 2):

**NEVER delete Items of TList in the FOR loop.**

The issue in this line:

```
  ListBox1.Items.Delete (i);
```

The loop goes from i:=0 to 2. Item - 0 is selected and you delete it. What we got on the next repeat? i=1 but here are only 2 items left instead of 3 (all following items shifted) and i points at the last item not the second. On the next repeat when i=3 we will get "Index out of bound" error. You should delete Item only after FOR loop to avoid this issue.

```
procedure TForm1.btnMoveLeftClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sString : String;
  i : Integer;
  k: integer;
begin
  k:=-1; 
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
      {-- Is this status selected? --}
      if ListBox1.Selected[i] then
      begin
        sString := Trim(ListBox1.Items[i]);

        {-- Delete selected status. --}
          k:=i;         

        if ((grdVFormDetails.RowCount >= 1) And (Trim(grdVFormDetails.Cells[0, 0]) <> EmptyStr)) then
          grdVFormDetails.RowCount := grdVFormDetails.RowCount+1;

        grdVFormDetails.Cols[1].Add(Copy(sString, 1, Pos('(', sString) - 1));

        sString := Copy(sString, Pos('(', sString) + 1, Length(sString));
        sString := Copy(sString, Pos('(', sString) + 1, Length(sString) - 1);

        grdVFormDetails.Cols[0].Add(sString);


        break;
      end;
  end;
  if k>=0 then  ListBox1.Items.Delete (k);

end;
```

Comment: I agree with you, but I have already put the "break" statement when deleting the item in the TListBox.

Comment: I've made a test D7 project with you handler and it works fine. So check all TListBox event handlers. I think something happens between you select an item and click the Button. Or After?.

Comment: There is no event handler code for my TListBox as well as TStringGrid components. This I am trying in the sample project.

Comment: @valex, ad your note, *"NEVER delete Items of TList in the FOR loop"*, why ? Just use `downto` loop and delete the items from bottom to top.

Comment: @TLama, Agree. But carefully if for example you want to point next item (i+1).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Delphi installed at the moment, though as far as I remember, if ListBox1.Selected[i] then will not give you correct result. You need to get the item firstly,
them check if the item is selected.

Comment: If I put the break point and see the value which is collected in the "sString" variable, which I found is correct. Moreover when the values are inserted into the grid those are also correct, but the moment I come out of this procedure, I find the last item's data in the TListBox is added to the TStringGrid and the last item data still resides in the TListbox too. This is the observation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have multi-select in the ListBox, better use the ItemIndex property, which gives you the Index of the selected Item, thus you don't have to loop to check all the Items in the list.

Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.btnMoveLeftClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sString : String;
  i : Integer;
begin
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    sString := Trim(ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex]);
    //do all your processing here
    //and at the end:
    ListBox1.Items.Delete(ListBox1.ItemIndex);
  end
end;
```

Comment: I tried your code as follows, but still same issue is happening.

Comment: Then your code is changing the selected element before reaching this. Put a breakpoint there and check the ItemIndex in the first if. If it is not what you selected, then go back to your code and check for any ItemIndex manipulation or messages sent to the ListBox.

Comment: As I said, if I put the break point and see the value which is collected in the "sString" variable is correct and the correct values are getting filled up in the grid. The issue is when I come out of this procedure, grid displays last item related data in the TListBox. Strange, but true.

Comment: This is happening in your code. When you reach the end line, continue stepping trough the code with <kbd>F8</kbd> and check where it goes, as there's the answer for that weird behavior.

Comment: The control goes to "procedure TApplication.Run;" of "Forms.pas" file and it continues execution in repeat..until loop all the time and nerver comes out until I press the "F9" key. Till that time there is no clue where it is going wrong.

Comment: I just did a test with my delphi and all works ok, create a new project and add this unit: [pas](http://pastebin.com/rgwrk2Rt) and [dfm](http://pastebin.com/36YsuDq3).  it is created under Delphi XE3, just ignore the properties doesn't exists in your ancient Delphi, compile and run.

Comment: @Vishal if something goes wrong with my example, blame your Delphi compiler. (does it have all available updates applied?)

Comment: I am not saying your code is wrong. The code is correct. I am just putting the observation happening with my Delphi.

Comment: @Vishal did you try the form I uploaded to pastebin? What about the updates question?

Comment: I do not know what is "pastebin", because I have never heard about it, could you help me out on how to download your uploaded form, then I could try it. On updates I am not sure, but since it is a fundamental program, so I feel it should work straight away.

Comment: This is the pas: http://pastebin.com/rgwrk2Rt and this the dfm: http://pastebin.com/36YsuDq3

Comment: Oh, it seems that the page is blocked here, let me go home and try downloading you code, then I would let you know, probably tomorrow. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Just FYI... I tried putting two TEditBoxes on the same form, Edit1 to store the value while filling value in column one and another Edit2 to store the value while filling value in column two. Strange !!! but TRUE, using the same variable I am tring to assign the value to these two edit boxes, they are displaying the CORRECT values where as grid is displaying the wrong values i.e. last item's data of TListBox.

Comment: I forgot to mention here that first I am moving the data from TStringGrid to TListBox, and then while moving the data to the TStringGrid I am facing this issue. So kindly refer the "btnMoveRightClick" procedure which I have written in the entire source code.

Comment: it looks like it is related to that previous opperation and the way you're adding new rows. Check my example, as I do the assignment in a different way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21053/discussion-between-vishal-tiwari-and-jachguate)